# What technique does Wikipedia use to convert non-latin characters to be ID safe?

Tags: html, html4

I am trying to auto-generate IDs for headings, to be used as anchor links. Because we don't know what language the heading is in, it should work for any language and not create illegal characters.

So I was looking at Wikipedia to see how it does that job, but can't figure out how exactly they are doing it. For example, the heading `Ссылки` is transformed to `.D0.A1.D1.81.D1.8B.D0.BB.D0.BA.D0.B8`, and used as the ID of the heading DOM.

Does anyone have any insight as to how that's done?

Comment: since the letter `a` is valid in HTML IDs, I suppose replacing every character with the letter `a` should work to make sure your words are valid as IDs. I would hazard a guess that you don't find this a particularly useful technique, so I would recommend that you spend more time articulating what it is exactly that you expect, and showing more details about what you've already tried.

Comment: Easy (but not necessarily practical) ones are base64 or a hash. Easy and possibly practical: a prefix with an index. But without a bit more context, we can only make wild guesses...

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks for the feedback, well I've reworked my question entirely, hopefully now it's much more specific and answerable.

Comment: @jcaron thanks for the insight, I've reworked the question though to be much more specific and hopefully it's much easier to answer now.

Comment: Hint: `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I've figured it out. Wikipedia is using Latin-1 encoding to represent the text as hex code for each byte. Following is some Ruby code I wrote to demonstrate the process:

```
# for arbitrary input `text`, force encode with Latin-1
encoded_text = text.force_encoding('iso-8859-1')

# Extract the string as plaintext, with literal hex escape character "/x"
plaintext_encoded_text = /\A"(.*)"\z/.match(encoded_text.inspect)[1]

# Replace "/x" with "." and spaces with "-"
output = plaintext_encoded_text.gsub('\x', '.').gsub(/\s/, '-')
```

This process will convert `Ссылки` to `.D0.A1.D1.81.D1.8B.D0.BB.D0.BA.D0.B8`, which is matching what appears on Wikipedia. Also, Latin characters are not affected.